# getting any overlaps even when rotated

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, konvajs

I have been learning about konva and html canvas and with the help of the community here I have a canvas with draggable shapes which stay in the bounds of the stage even when rotated.

Also, my konva code is detecting intersections in dragboundfunc and setting strokeEnabled to true if a intersection is detected. I was using my own collision detection code/function until yesterday but because I wasn't getting correct detection results when shapes had been rotated I changed my code to put the shape being dragged in a tempLayer to enable getIntersection to work during dragBoundFunc hoping that would fix it but it didn't.

My problem is I cannot get correct collision detection even with getIntersection rather than my own collision detection code and have spent since last night trying. I can get it detecting collision fine if the shape rotation is 0 using the code below which is my shapes dragBoundFunc.

I know I can't be far off but I'm also at a loss. I also know the part of my code where I set collisionz is probably the wrong way of going about this even though it works for 0 degrees rotation but I have left it in to show what I have tried and that I am trying.

Does anyone know the answer to help me on my way with Konva please?

```
function theDragFunc(pos) {

var thisRect;
if(parseInt(this.getClientRect().width) != parseInt(this.width())){
if(userRotation == 90 || userRotation == 270)
thisRect = {x: this.x(), y: this.y(), width: this.getClientRect().height, height: this.getClientRect().width};
else
thisRect = {x: this.x(), y: this.y(), width: this.getClientRect().width, height: this.getClientRect().height};
console.log("must have changed userRotation = "+userRotation);
}
else{
thisRect = {x: this.x(), y: this.y(), width: this.width(), height: this.height()};
console.log("must not have changed userRotation = " +userRotation);
}

 isCollision = false;

// copy the boundary rect into a testRect which defines the extent of the dragbounds without
// accounting for the width and height of dragging rectangle.
// This is changed below depending on rotation.
var testRect={
  left: boundary.x, 
  top: boundary.y, 
  right: boundary.x + boundary.width,
  bottom: boundary.y + boundary.height
};


// the userRotation value is calculated in the rotation button onclick 
// to be one of 0, 90, 180, 270
switch (userRotation){

  case 0: // for 0 degrees compute as per a normal bounds rect
    testRect.right = testRect.right - thisRect.width;
    testRect.bottom = testRect.bottom - thisRect.height;
    break;


  case 90:  // for 90 degs we have to modify the test boundary left and bottom 
    testRect.left = testRect.left + thisRect.height;
    testRect.bottom = testRect.bottom - thisRect.width;
    break;

  case 180:  // for 180 degs we have to modify the test boundary left and top 
    testRect.left = testRect.left + thisRect.width;
    testRect.top = testRect.top + thisRect.height;
    break;

  case 270:  // for 270 degs we have to modify the test boundary right and top 
    testRect.right = testRect.right - thisRect.height;
    testRect.top = testRect.top + thisRect.width;
    break;

}

// get new pos as: if pos inside bounday ranges then use it, otherwise user boundary
var newX = (pos.x < testRect.left ? testRect.left : pos.x);

// looking at the far x pos we need to consider width of the dragging rect...
newX = (newX > testRect.right ? testRect.right : newX);

// get new pos as: if pos inside bounday ranges then use it, otherwise user boundary
var newY = (pos.y < testRect.top ? testRect.top : pos.y);

// looking at the far y pos we need to consider height of the dragging rect...      
newY = (newY > testRect.bottom ? testRect.bottom : newY);


 var collisionz = stage.getIntersection({x:newX+this.getClientRect().width,y:newY}, ".rect");
 if(!collisionz)collisionz = stage.getIntersection({x:newX,y:newY}, ".rect");
 else if(!collisionz)collisionz = stage.getIntersection({x:newX,y:newY+this.getClientRect().height}, ".rect");
 else if(!collisionz)collisionz = stage.getIntersection({x:newX,y:newY+this.getClientRect().height/2}, ".rect");
 else if(!collisionz)collisionz = stage.getIntersection({x:newX+this.getClientRect().width,y:newY+this.getClientRect().height/2}, ".rect");
 else if(!collisionz)collisionz = stage.getIntersection({x:newX + this.getClientRect().height/2,y:newY + this. getClientRect().height}, ".rect");
 if(!collisionz)collisionz = stage.getIntersection({x:newX + this.getClientRect().width,y:newY + this.getClientRect().height}, ".rect");
 var search_term = 'funcRect';


        if(collisionz && collisionz != this){
console.log("INTERSECTION detected"+collisionz.getName());
isCollision = true;
        }
        else
        isCollision = false;

    if(!isCollision && this.getStrokeEnabled())
    {
        this.setStrokeEnabled(false);
        layer.draw();
    }
    else if(isCollision && !this.getStrokeEnabled())
    {
        this.setStrokeWidth(2);
        this.setStroke('black');
        this.setStrokeEnabled(true);
        layer.draw();

    }
return {
x: newX,
y: newY
}   



}
```

Comment: What type of shapes are you using? Collision detection can be a challenging problem but there are some simplifications that can be applied where there low numbers and the shapes are mostly standard geometric or vector-drawn.

Comment: The shapes are only ever going to be rectangles and the angles are limited to 0,90,180 and 270. I can sense there is a simple algorithm and I am still doing trial and error now but not yet sussed it.

Comment: ok cool - so roughly how many shapes on the canvas, tens, 50's, 100's, thousands ?

Comment: tens max, it's just a floor planner where the user can drag some units onto the canvas without having to worry about overlaps (hopefully!).

Comment: Ok - so you want to construct an array of positions and use some uber-simple overlap math to recognise the overlap. We can probably extend the rotated bounds func to give us what we need.

Comment: I have already tried that (I think) before I changed to getIntersection instead I had a function called checkCollision and I looped my shapes array and it worked great but failed for rotated shapes as getIntersection does. Some more investigation today tells me that depending on the angle the shape has been rotated to the x or y values will be off by the width or height of the shape. I tried to benefit from this investigation but still didn't find a fool proof solution.

Comment: Finally solved it by going back to looping through my shapes coordinates and checking if they overlap in a simple js overlap function but one of the rectangles I passed into this function (the pressed shape) has it's x or y coordinates minus by width or height depending on rotation value and then the one that got me was that I had to do this also with the shape out of the array I was checking against - if it had also been rotated then minus width or height from x or y of this rectangle I create as well before passing this to check if it collides.

Comment: ok - I started on a solution based on a modified version of the rotation boundsFunc approach from your other question. I will complete it an add it here as an answer shortly.

Comment: Thanks Vanquished Wombat, I also want to thank you for the code you posted a couple of months ago to drag onto a konva stage using draggables. Finding that has saved me many hours of coding tonight :)